# How to call different method given specific argument class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say we have these code:

```
class Parent {}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {}

class Main {
    static void method(Parent obj) {}
    static void method(Child1 obj) {}
    static void method(Child2 obj) {}
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Parent obj1 = new Child1();
        Parent obj2 = new Child2();
        method(obj1); //call method(Child1 obj)
        method(obj2); //call method(Child2 obj)
    }
}
```

How can I get similar effect, so object can be delivered to concrete method instead of the general one?

------------------------Serveral Parameters Example--------------

```
class Parent {}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {}

class Main {
    static void method(Parent obj1, Parent obj2) {}

    static void method(Child1 obj1, Child1 obj2) {}

    static void method(Child1 obj1, Child2 obj2) {}

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Parent obj1 = new Child1();
        Parent obj2 = new Child2();
        method(obj1, obj1); //call method(Child1 obj1, Child1 obj2)
        method(obj1, obj2); //call method(Child1 obj1, Child2 obj2)
    }
}
```

Comment: @ernest_k visitor design pattern is a good way for this example, but if a method has several parameters which inherits `Parent`, it seems not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background: I come up with nearly the same problem when writing a compiler project.

**Short Answer**: If you stick to making the code **extensible** and easy to write as well (just as code samples in the question), presumably, you have to add reflections to it (though it may not be friendly to static analyzers).

Example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

class Value {}

class IntValue extends Value {
    private int value;
    public int value() {
        return value;
    }
    public IntValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}

class StringValue extends Value {
    private String value;
    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
    public StringValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Operator {
    public Value apply(Value x, Value y) throws ArithmeticException {
        try {
            var method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("apply", x.getClass(), y.getClass());
            return (Value) method.invoke(this, x, y);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException exception) {
            throw (ArithmeticException) exception.getCause();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private IntValue apply(IntValue x, IntValue y) {
        return new IntValue(x.value() / y.value());
    }

    private StringValue apply(StringValue x, StringValue y) {
        return new StringValue(x.value() + y.value());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var op = new Operator();

        System.out.println(op.apply(new IntValue(6), new IntValue(2)));
        System.out.println(op.apply(new StringValue("a_str"), new StringValue("b_str")));

        try {
            System.out.println(op.apply(new IntValue(6), new IntValue(0)));
        } catch (ArithmeticException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about it method overloading. Method overloading is resolved at compile time, and therefore uses the compile-time type of the relevant variables to determine which method to execute.

Therefore `method(obj1`) and `method(obj2)` will always call `static void method(Parent obj)`, since the compile time type of `obj1` and `obj2` is `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution like this:

```
class Parent {}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {}

public class Main {
    static void method(Parent obj) {
        System.out.println("Parent");
        if(obj instanceof Child1)
        {
            method((Child1) obj);
            return;
        } else if(obj instanceof Child2)
        {
            method((Child2) obj);
            return;
        }
    }
    static void method(Child1 obj) {
        System.out.println("Child1");
    }
    static void method(Child2 obj) {
        System.out.println("Child2");
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Parent obj1 = new Child1();
        Parent obj2 = new Child2();
        method(obj1); //call method(Child1 obj)
    }
}
```

For this code the output is :

```
Parent
Child1
```

So it means that when we put the object of type Child1 then method for Parent will be invoked and then it checks inside this method if object is type of Child1, if yes then invoke method for Child1.

Until the object passed as argument to this method is type of Parent there is no way to invoke Child1 or Child2

Comment: but if `Parent` has lots of child classes, these `if-else1` clauses will be ugly